# no emulator binary found,mksdcard.exe missing from sdk tools

Tags: android-virtual-device

I am using the following:

> - Android Studio 1.4
> - Windows 7 x64 PC

I installed  Android Studio in the `D:` drive.

Now whenever I click the run option, it throws the errors,

```
no emulator binary found
```

and

```
mksdcard.exe missing from sdk tools folder
```

I cant even create avd. It is just showing `saving avd` .

I removed and  installed haxxm once again although it still wont work. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

**Quick tip** that fixed error in my case:

1. Move everything from "emulator/emulator" to just "emulator" level in sdk directory

OR

2. Reinstall emulator via GUI

**TL;DR**

My error in "idea.log" was:
*vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - 'mksdcard' is missing from the SDK tools folder*

My environment:
*macOS Big Sur, Android Studio 4.1*

How to find "idea.log": Help | Show Log in Finder

Solution that worked for me:

1. Note down "Android SDK Location" (see Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK)
2. Open the path from #1 in Finder or other file manager
3. Make sure "emulator" folder is there

**In my case the required file was located 1 level lower, namely at "emulator/emulator" subfolder of sdk, not just "emulator"**

4. Move everything from second level of "emulator/emulator" to first "emulator"

NB: I would have preferred symlink'ing the items, but the "emulator" directory contains an executable named "emulator" so there was a conflict of already existing name. Besides, reinstalling via GUI (*see next solution below*) creates just 1st level of "emulator" which proofs that moving is OK.

OR

**Re-install emulator:**

1. Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK | SDK Tools | Android Emulator
2. Clean checkbox, "Apply" (this will remove emulator)
3. Mark checkbox, "Apply" (install emulator anew)

The issue can still happen in 2021. I'm not sure about the reason it took place six years ago. I had multiple errors related to the fact that Android Studio 4.1 downloads files to one location but expects them to be within folder at an upper level. This also concerns settings folder that moved from "/Users/*sign-in_name*/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio4.0" to "/Users/*sign-in_name*/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1"